# XSLT - get node closest to current timestamp

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I've got a set of nodes with dates in timestamp format that I'm iterating over with `<xsl:for-each>`. How would I get the node closest to the current date saved in `$currentDate`?

```
 <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="1396332574" />

 <items>
   <item>
      <tmstmp>1374249600</tmstmp>
   </item>
   <item>
      <tmstmp>1374249600</tmstmp>
   </item>
   <item>
      <tmstmp>1374257700</tmstmp>
   </item>
   <item>
      <tmstmp>1374418800</tmstmp>
   </item>
   <item>
      <tmstmp>2777068800</tmstmp>
   </item>
 </items>
```

Comment: from the above `tmstmp`, what is your expected output?

Comment: edit: added node for clarification...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="1396332574" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <xsl:sort select="$currentDate - ." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
<item>
   <tmstmp>1374418800</tmstmp>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, as the furthest date will always be on top. I need the closest date (closest to zero in your code). I guess sorting it via an abs value would work though.

Comment: Please see this (http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8o). It outputs what I posted above. Is `1374418800` closest to `1396332574`?

Comment: you can use xpath expressions on the `select` attribute of `xsl:sort`, as what I have done above.

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8o/5 the current date is 1st april 2014. The last node is 1st january 2058, which isn't the closest to the current date. +1 for giving me direction

Comment: ($currentDate - ./tmstmp)*(($currentDate - ./tmstmp) >=0) - ($currentDate - ./tmstmp)*(($currentDate - ./tmstmp) &lt; 0) does the trick

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can use the abs() function. In XSLT 1.0 the equivalent is `number(translate(string(XXX), '-', ''))`, i.e. convert to a string, strip the minus sign, then convert back to a number.

Comment: @MichaelKay **In this case**, converting back to number is redundant since the `<xsl:sort>` element will ignore it and make its own data type conversion.